# Redirect back to a specific tab in Laravel when Validate has error

Tags: laravel, redirect

I have 4 tabs. When the information is updated and there is no error, I can display the same tab after returning.
That's how I set the tab:

```
return redirect(route('frontend.user.account') . '#edit')->with(['tab' => 'edit']);
```

Now, suppose there's an error in the update. How can I specify my preferred tab, like the above code??

this is update function :

```
    public function update(UpdateProfileRequest $request)
    {
        $output = $this->userRepository->update(
            $request->user()->id,
            $request->only('first_name', 'last_name', 'email','national_Code','phone_number','mobile_number','state','city','address','postal_code', 'avatar_type', 'avatar_location'),
            $request->has('avatar_location') ? $request->file('avatar_location') : false
        );

        return redirect(route('frontend.user.account') . '#edit')->with(['tab' => 'edit']);

    }
```

Comment: you can do it on the client side, using js, and don't overload controllers with quite useless code

Answer (score 1):

The solution for us was to add the tab to the form action.

`<form ... action="{{ url()->current() }}/tabname`